# Adding List - two different methods

Tags: c#, list, object, appendto

I have a list of ClassRooms and then I get a list of students inside that classroom. Here in this method, I create a list of ClassRoom first. then I get the list of students in that classroom. Now when I am trying to add the list of students to the first list. I get this error.

> The best overload method match for List... has invalid arguments

```
public static List<MyList> getRecords()
{
    int id = 10;
    int id2 = 20;
    List<MyList> ClassRooms = GetClassRooms(id);
    foreach(MyList Students in ClassRooms)
    {
        List<MyList> studentProfile = GetStudentProfile(id, Students.ID);
        foreach(MyList studentDetail in studentProfile) ClassRooms.Add(studentDetail);
    }   
    return ClassRooms;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE -

```
public class MyList
{
    public int ID;
    public string Class Number;
    public bool Active;
    public int StudentID;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public int TotalStudents;
}
```

Comment: OMG this is so scarring

Comment: @AndreCalil: scary or scarring?

Comment: Could you provide more info about `MyList` class, please?

Comment: Despite the confusing names, there's one problem: you cannot modify a list (like adding new items) while iterating it, as you're doing with `ClassRooms`.

Comment: So, `ClassRooms` is a list of type `MyList` which can be either a student or a Student Detail? In any case, Andre is correct. You're iterating over the list while adding new items to it, which won't work.

Comment: Dang!!! thanks Colin for clarifying... maybe I should try a different approach

Comment: Indeed, you should have a `Class` class and a `Student` class. `Class` would have a `List<Student>`.

Comment: that is what I am doing right now @AndreCalil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to rethink your class structure and variable names. I'm not sure what MyList is supposed to represent, a student or a classroom. You can solve the problem at hand with a Select statement, though:

```
List<MyList> ClassRooms = GetClassRooms(id)
    .Select(classroom => GetStudentProfile(id, classroom.ID));
return ClassRooms;
```

This will take each class in the list of classrooms, call GetStudentProfile on it, and add that to the list.

Comment: Thanks Otaia... Although I ended up using two different class. Your solution is not a bad idea. Thanks for your answer